# How to access class element variable in React/TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a class level variable that I want to be able to access in my functions. I thought this worked like a global variable but I'm new to this. This is the simplified code I have right now that is not working:

```
class People extends React.Component<PeopleProps, {}> {
    public isAdmin: boolean = false;
    public render() {
        return <div onClick={this._checkAdmin}>Call function</div>;
    }

    private _checkAdmin() {
        if (this.isAdmin) {
            console.log("is admin");
        }
    }
}
```

The error occurs on the if statement. The error I am getting is Uncaught

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAdmin' of null

I am assuming that `this` is undefined but I'm not sure how that could happen. There are no errors in VS before building this. I can get to the `_checkAdmin` function so it seems like `this` is working there. Do I need to pass an argument to '_checkAdmin'?

Answer (score 0):

Missed binding this

```
class People extends React.Component<PeopleProps, {}> {
    public isAdmin: boolean = false;
    public render() {
        return <div onClick={this._checkAdmin.bind(this)}>Call function</div>;
    }

    private _checkAdmin() {
        if (this.isAdmin) {
            console.log("is admin");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said cooper, you forgot bind this. But you don't care about this if you use arrow functions:

```
class People extends React.Component<PeopleProps, {}> {
    public isAdmin: boolean = false;
    public render() {
        return <div onClick={this._checkAdmin}>Call function</div>;
    }

    private _checkAdmin = () => {
        if (this.isAdmin) {
            console.log("is admin");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am passing _checkAdmin() to another component and when that component call this method as this.props._checkAdmin I got undefined. Any inputs what  am I missing here